# Open MS access databases for legacy apps on Win server 2008 R2 x64 (JET OLEDB 4.0)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a new server (Win 2008R2, x64) with some legacy applications which I need to run on it. The previous server (and underlying connections) used the Jet OLE DB 4.0 engine which doesn't seem to be present at the current state.

Searched MS download sites extensively, but all I got were updates that were "not applicable". So my question, can I register some components or what do I need to do to get these apps running (and reading those files)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've found the solution. Althought this download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D is NOT intended

> 2.As a replacement for the Jet OLEDB Provider in server-side applications

It works though. And because I just need it to import old data into the new situation it works for me.
Changed the connectionstring-part from Provider=JET.OLE to:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```